# Parse class object through parameter with function in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I want to pass object through function.

Error : It show me no member in object

**Function**

```
func startLoading(_ whichClass: Any) {

 whichClass!.startAnimating()

}
```

**Callback Function**

```
let vControllerMe = ControllerMe()

startLoading(vControllerMe)
```

it is possible to parse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a protocol if you intend to pass instances of various classes.

```
protocol Animatable {
    func startAnimating();
}

extension ControllerMe: Animatable {
    func startAnimating() {
        // here goes your animation code
    }
}
func startLoading(_ whichClass: Animatable) {
    whichClass.startAnimating()
}
```

Then you can pass in any instances of classes that adhere to `Animatable` protocol.

```
let vControllerMe = ControllerMe()

startLoading(vControllerMe)
```